# On The General Form of Passive Sentences (and a few active ones)

Tags: word-order, grammaticality

When working with the Vorgangspassiv, would it be correct to view some potential general forms of the various tenses as follows (i know besides V2, word order is less strict in German, but nonetheless these could be considered correct, yes?)

**Simple Present Passive:**

Das Buch wird gelesen
[Subject] [conjugated present-tense of werden] [partizip II of main verb]

**Present Perfekt Passive:**

Das Buch ist gelesen worden
[Subject] [conjugated present tense of sein] [partizip II of main verb] worden.

**Simple Past Passive:**

Das Buch wurde gelesen
[subject] [conjugated simple past tense of werden] [partizip II of main verb]

**Past Perfekt (plusquam perfekt) Passive:**

Das Buch war gelesen worden
[Subject] [conjugated past tense of sein] [partizip II of main verb] worden.

**Simple Future Passive (Future I):**

Das Buch wird gelesen werden.
[subject] [conjugated present tense of werden] [partizip II of main verb] werden

**Perfekt Future Passive (Future II):**

Das Buch wird gelesen worden sein
[subject] [conjugated present tense of werden] [partizip II of main verb] worden sein

---

**Question** When a form of 'sein' is being used (for example, in the present perfekt passive example) is this just by coincidence that the verb takes sein and not haben? Or will such a construction *always* take sein? For example, in Future II active, the infinitive placed at the end of the sentence can be either haben/sein depending on which aux the verb takes in the present perfket tense.

so the question is, should the general form really be
[Subject] [conjugated present tense of sein/haben] [partizip II of main verb] worden.

---

Now, when working with Active Future I and Future II, is the following right?

**Future I Active:**

Ich werde das Buch lesen
[subject] [conjugated present tense of werden] [object if applicable] [inf. form of main verb]

**Future II Active:**

Ich werde das Buch gelesen haben
[subject] [conjugated present tense of werden] [object if applicable] [partizip II of main verb] haben/sein

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, all your "phrase plans" are correct.

Here's a more condensed version of the construction principle of the *werden* passive (see eg Helbig/Buscha, *Deutsche Grammatik*, 2001, 144; Hentschel/Weydt, *Handbuch der deutschen Grammatik*, 5th edn 2021, 118f; Engel, *Deutsche Grammatik*, Neunbearbeitung, 2nd edn 2009, 238): 1. The *werden* passive consists of the conjugated form of the passive auxiliary *werden* and the participle II of the full verb. 2. The participle II of *werden* is always used without leading *ge-*.

So, for example, the perfect of *(er/sie/es) wird* is *ist geworden*. Now combine it with the participle II of the full verb, you get: *ist gelesen geworden*, elide the *ge-* from *geworden*, and you get *ist gelesen worden*. Or preterite: The preterite of *wird* is *wurde*, add the participle II of *lesen*, and you get *wurde gelesen*.   Future II: The future II of *wird* is *wird geworden sein*, add the participle II of *lesen*, elide the *ge-* from *geworden*, et voilà: *wird gelesen worden sein*.

You ask:

> When a form of 'sein' is being used (for example, in the present perfekt passive example) is this just by coincidence that the verb takes sein and not haben? Or will such a construction always take sein?

Yes, it is always *sein*, and that's no coincidence. You get that information from the above rule, by the way: The *sein* in perfect tense comes in due the fact that the perfect auxiliary of *werden* is *sein*. It does not come from the full verb. Because the future II incorporates the perfect auxiliary as well, it too contains *sein*.